# Repository within repository, removing the repository that contains the second one while maintaining the files within

Tags: git, repository

By mistake a couple of weeks ago, I added to a local repository an entire folder(let's name it Projects) and within I have multiple sub folders and files.

Within Projects/AProjectName/Git , I've made a repository which has as parent folder Git. When I go to terminal it detects my original repository (Projects) and adds all the files starting from Projects within not just from Git.

How can I make the terminal remove the repository from Projects? I normally want the repositories to be at the level of Git, while also painting all the files within Projects.

Any tips on how to stop seeing Projects as a repository but still keeping the files within?

Answer (score 0):

Because most of the files that were inside the Projects folder were already on gitHub, and were small projects that were finished, I've went to Projects and deleted all the .git files that were inside with the command.

```
$ rm -rf .git*
```